# Firefox window.parent.location

Tags: firefox, redirect, window.location, window.parent

I've a Html page index.htm which has an iframe to page search.htm
the search.htm has code like this

```
function executeSearch() {     
        window.parent.location = "/SearchResults.aspx?t=" + txt_Search.value;
    }
```

this code executed now from index.htm page and it works great on IE and Chrome, but not FireFox ... is there any work around ?? 
I tried window.parent.location.href, window.opener.location, window.parent.document.location ... but nothing of those worked.

after searching the web i found some one with similar prob he said that this is a security settings in Firefox ... is this true?? and if so is there any workaround ?

Comment: Do you get any security error in the console? Can you post code example?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `window.top.location.href` instead.